# Xamarin Forms Pop Out Navigation Empty on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have made a cross platform app with Xamarin Forms that relies on a pop out style navigation menu (Navigation Master Detail page) to switch between views.

On iOS simulators the navigation behaves as intended; however on physical devices the navigation menu is empty.

I have tested several version of iOS to rule out compatibility issues, and I've confirmed the UI elements are loading correctly - this has confirmed the list data is not loading.

Here is my Navigation Master code behind:

```
public partial class NavigationMaster : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView;

    public NavigationMaster()
    {
        Icon = Services.PlatformImage.Resolver("menu.png");
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new NavigationMasterViewModel();
        ListView = MenuItemsListView;
    }

    class NavigationMasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuItem> _menuItems = new ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuItem> MenuItems
        {
            get { return _menuItems; }
            set
            {
                _menuItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MenuItems));
            }
        }

        public NavigationMasterViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<NavigationMenuItem>(new[]
            {
                new NavigationMenuItem { Id = 1, Title = "Projects", TargetType = typeof(Views.Projects)},
                new NavigationMenuItem { Id = 2, Title = "Tickets", TargetType = typeof(Views.Tickets)},
                new NavigationMenuItem { Id = 3, Title = "Documents", TargetType = typeof(Views.Documents)},
                new NavigationMenuItem { Id = 4, Title = "Calendar", TargetType = typeof(Views.Calendar)},
                new NavigationMenuItem { Id = 5, Title = "Discussion", TargetType = typeof(Views.Discussion)},
            });
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And my XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
              HasUnevenRows="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
              >
        <ListView.Header>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#222222">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="Logo.png" Margin="40" Scale="0.5" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                               TextColor="#000000"
                               VerticalOptions="Start"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                               FontSize="Small"
                               Margin="10"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the linker behaviour configuration - if linking is disabled the navigation list does not populate.

Setting the linker behavior to "Link Framework SDKs Only" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the system version and model of   iOS simulators different from your real device? Try to delete two folders "obj" and "bin" under your forms project,and rebuild it.

Comment: Yes the system versions and models are the same, I've also tried different models and versions and the simulators consistently work as intended.

Comment: I've deleted the "obj" and "bin" folders and rebuilt. Unfortunately no change.

Comment: I put a break point on "if (PropertyChanged == null)" and on initial launch of the app it returns true on both the simulators and devices.

Running on devices though, the subsequent return statement is skipped.

Comment: I can't review your situation .Can you provide your project?